# Application specific warning shown on install of an iOS application

Tags: ios

As soon as my application is installed from test flight, I see the following error in the logs.

```
Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged.
```

Why do I see the app specific error even before the application is launched? Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you do not have a proper view controller hierarchy. Set the rootviewcontroller of the app and then show new views by pushing or presenting new view controllers on them. Let each view controller manage their views. Only container view controllers, like the tabbarviewcontroller, should ever add other view controllers views to their own views. Read the view controllers programming guide to learn more on how to use view controllers properly.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I am working on handling the view hierarchy as mentioned by you. I found the same answer elsewhere in stack overflow before asking this question. My actual question is why would application installation throw an error which as I understand should have been thrown if the application was launched.